How to match csv start with empty item?
Currently I'm using:
\v(((^|,)[^,]*){3})(.*)

to match csv lines, the first part ((^|,)[^,]*){3} is to match 3 items, then the second part .* matches the rest.
However, if the csv line starts with a empty item, e.g. ,2,3,4,5, the regex will not match correctly, as ^ seems can be matched multiple times.
How could I avoid this, to make ^ matched only once?
Of course I can use:
\v(^[^,]*)((,[^,]*){2})(.*)

but then the matching items increased and other codes become more complex. I wonder if there is a "local" fix here.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further?

To match an empty line I would do:
^,*$

Basically matching a line that is full of ,.
Where:

^ match the start of the line
$ match the end of the line

To match the first three items (including empty onces) I would do:
\v^([^,]*,){2}[^,]*

If the third item must ends with, then you do:
\v^([^,]*,){3}

Remark: in your example ^ is not matching multiple times but (^|,) is matching multiple times.
Remark: you can prefix the () with % to avoid that () captures. More information with: :help /\%

yeah... but then the last item would be different ie not ending with , . there are other codes using the regex result, so if it can be (^|,)[^,]* style to match an item that would be much easier...

If the third item must end with , then the answer would be: \v^([^,]*,){3}
